# iMac 27" 2017 Fusion drive only appears as HDD

Tags: macos, display, imac, hdd, 5k

I bought a 2017 5k iMac. It has a 1 TB FusionDrive, but the system only recognizes it as a plain HDD. I already tried to delete it in the disk manager, I reinstalled Monterey, but nothing changed.
I tried several things in the Terminal, but nothing works, diskutil resetFusion, diskutil cs delete "Macintosh HD", etc.

I will listen to any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste the text results from running "diskutil list" into your original question, that will help us diagnose this.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? i.e. what are you trying to accomplish by deleting the drive?